# R cumulative sum by condition with reset

Tags: r, dplyr, cumulative-sum, running-count

I have a vector of numbers in a data.frame such as below.

```r
df <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3,4,2,3,4,5,8,9,10,1,2,1))
```

I need to create a new column which gives a running count of entries that are greater than their predecessor. The resulting column vector should be this:

```
0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,0,1,0
```

My attempt is to create a "flag" column of diffs to mark when the values are greater.

```r
df$flag <- c(0,diff(df$a)>0)
> df$flag
```

```
0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0
```

Then I can apply some dplyr group/sum magic to almost get the right answer, except that the sum doesn't reset when flag == 0:

```r
df %>% group_by(flag) %>% mutate(run=cumsum(flag))
```

```
    a flag run
1   1    0   0
2   2    1   1
3   3    1   2
4   4    1   3
5   2    0   0
6   3    1   4
7   4    1   5
8   5    1   6
9   8    1   7
10  9    1   8
11 10    1   9
12  1    0   0
13  2    1  10
14  1    0   0
```

I don't want to have to resort to a for() loop because I have several of these running sums to compute with several hundred thousand rows in a data.frame.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here's one way with `ave`:

```
ave(df$a, cumsum(c(F, diff(df$a) < 0)), FUN=seq_along) - 1
 [1] 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 0 1 0
```

We can get a running count grouped by `diff(df$a) < 0`. Which are the positions in the vector that are less than their predecessors. We add `c(F, ..)` to account for the first position. The cumulative sum of that vector creates an index for grouping. The function `ave` can carry out a function on that index, we use `seq_along` for a running count. But since it starts at 1, we subtract by one `ave(...) - 1` to start from zero.

---

A similar approach using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(cumsum(c(FALSE, diff(a) < 0))) %>% 
  mutate(row_number() - 1)
```

Comment: Or with `dplyr` (as per the tag) `df %>% group_by(cumsum(c(FALSE, diff(a) < 0))) %>% mutate(row_number() - 1)`

Comment: Wow thanks. Works for me. I kept trying to do this with ave or rle, but couldn't put it together.

Comment: Thanks @DavidArenburg. added : ) Although I think the tag was for suggestive purposes as opposed to required method.

Comment: Yeah I'm not married to dplyr, I just thought it was the logical direction to go. Both answers look great. I'll do some timing benchmarks to see what works best in my situation. Thanks again; been stuck on this many hours since yesterday.

Answer (score 13):

You don't need dplyr:

```
fun <- function(x) {
  test <- diff(x) > 0
  y <- cumsum(test)
  c(0, y - cummax(y * !test))
}

fun(df$a)
[1] 0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 0 1 0
```

Comment: I've seen something like this on SO, but can't find it anymore. I would really like to give proper credit.

Answer (score 4):

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4,2,3,4,5,8,9,10,1,2,1)
f <- c(0, diff(a)>0)
ifelse(f, cumsum(f), f)
```

that it is without reset.
with reset:

```
unlist(tapply(f, cumsum(c(0, diff(a) < 0)), cumsum))
```