# Rolling sum of days that are 1, with a reset if the value is equal to 0

Tags: r

Assume that I have this data set

[image]

I would like this result

[image]

I am not sure how to do this, but here is my pseudocode

problem = if_else(problem == 0, 0, sum of all previous 1s)

I have tried

dataset <- dataset %>% mutate(problem = if_else(problem == 0, 0, problem + lag(problem))

That will only get me a 2 as the highest number.  How would I accomplish this.  Also, the column name for the total could be different from problem as well.

Comment: Relevant: [R cumulative sum by condition with reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32994060/r-cumulative-sum-by-condition-with-reset)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option with `data.table`.  Convert to `data.table` (`setDT`), grouped by the `rleid` (run-length-id) of 'Problem', multiply the 'Problem' with the row number (`seq_len(.N)`) and assign (`:=`) it to 'Problem'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, Problem := seq_len(.N) * Problem, rleid(Problem)]
df1
#    Problem
# 1:       0
# 2:       1
# 3:       2
# 4:       3
# 5:       0
# 6:       0
# 7:       1
# 8:       2
# 9:       0
#10:       0
#11:       1
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
with(rle(df1$Problem), sequence(lengths) * rep(values, lengths))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(Problem = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1))
```