# Rowsum with factors on complex array

Tags: r

I have a long complex array, on which I would like to do

```
rowsum(my_array, group = factors)
```

Unfortunately, rowsum does not accept complex numbers while rowSums does but does not accept factors, to average over the rows.

What would you would recommend?

Edit: example

```
my_array <- array(c(1+1i, -1-1i, 2, 0, 1+1i, 2+2i), dim = c(3, 2))
factors <- c(1, 1, 2)
```

Expected response:

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0 1+1i
[2,]    2 2+2i
```

2nd edit:

The factors are applied for each column individually and here `0 == 1+1i + (-1-1i)` and `1+1i == 0 + 1+1i`.

Comment: I think that this should be okay for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32994060/r-cumulative-sum-by-condition-with-reset

Comment: Please copy and paste your complex array with the expected output too. Thank you!

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Thank you @SlowLearning, I have looked at `dplyr` but `group_by` does not seem applicable to complex matrices. `ave()` provides interesting output but I cannot find a simple way to obtain the solution to the example I have added. Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`my_array` is

```
    [,1] [,2]
[1,]  1+1i 0+0i
[2,] -1-1i 1+1i
[3,]  2+0i 2+2i
```

From the expected response and from the 2nd edit, its clear that `factors` is used to split the array into the the following two arrays

```
 $`1`
   [,1] [,2]
   [1,]  1+1i 0+0i
   [2,] -1-1i 1+1i

   $`2`
   [,1] [,2]
   [1,] 2+0i 2+2i
```

and then the columns are to be summed for each array.  One way to do this in base R is as follows.  Use `by` to split the array into a list of arrays grouped by `factors` and then sum the columns of each array separately with `colSums`.  `colSums` is used since it can process complex numbers.

```
y <- by(my_array, factors, FUN = colSums)
```

which gives the somewhat wordy but clear result:

```
  INDICES: 1
      V1   V2 
    0+0i 1+1i
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
    INDICES: 2
      V1   V2 
    2+0i 2+2i
```

where V1 and V2 are the sums of columns of the arrays for each factor.
Finally we'll pull this into an array with

```
t(simplify2array(y))
```

which gives

```
    V1   V2
1 0+0i 1+1i
2 2+0i 2+2i
```

which is the expected response.

Comment: Thank you, and not as simple I would have thought! I am also very interested in knowing how it could work by summing rows, for instance summing over columns the transposed `t(my_array)` using the same `factors`.

Comment: The response I have given uses `rowsum` and not `rowSums`. In the example I gave, the (non-complex) values in the cells are summed row-wise with respect to the factors per row (not summing per column). Unfortunately, `rowsum`does not work on complex matrices (and btw I would prefer to do it per column rather than by row as I currently transpose my matrix).

Comment: For row 3 of your array which is associated with factor 2, the row sum can be easily calculated by entering  the values in the R console.  So   2  +  2+2i  gives 4+2i  which is the correct mathematical answer and what  my row sum calculation gives.

Comment: Hi @WaltS, I have tried to clarify further my initial text.

Comment: I think that perhaps you're using the `row sums` to mean what R would refer to a `column sums`.  Anyway, I've found a simpler solution in base R which gives your expected results and is consistent which your explanation in the calculation in your 2nd edit.  I've also tried to explain the steps to the result.   Sorry about the confusion.